# How to load an HTML file on an SDCARD in a browser using Android 11

Tags: sd-card, browser, android-11, url

Background

1. Using a file explorer I can select an HTML file and it will start the default browser and then do its thing.
2. The HTML file is on an inserted SDCARD
3. In the browser, the HTML file takes some options and displays text relevant to those options

The reverse does not work (The Problem):

1. In a browser I enter the path for the HTML file shown by the file explorer
2. An example: the file explorer shows the path as **/storage/####-####/folder/filename.html**
3. In the browser I enter **file://** then the path above (####-#### is 8 numbers in two sets of 4)
4. This generates the response: "Access to the file was denied: it is not readable. may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be preventing access."

There is no user code

I wish to enter the file URL within the browser so it can be bookmarked for easy future access

Comment: Android 11 uses scoped storage which means apps don't have any direct filesystem access to internal and external sdcard section. Hence the file protocol can not work on Android 11. This is why you are getting an access denied.

Comment: Robert, thank you.

Comment: I note a possible work-around. Load per Background point 1 above and "use" the result. Delete the tab in the browser.  Create a new tab and enter some key word from the URL.  Not always successful.